# Positioning labels on a donut-chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, excel-charts

I have the following code which attempts to add a datalabel to a point in a combined donut/pie-chart:

```
    For Each co In .ChartObjects
        With co.Chart.FullSeriesCollection("Grøn pil").Points(2)
            .HasDataLabel = True
            With .DataLabel
                .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
                .Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            End With
        End With
    Next co
```

However, the code aborts on the line `.Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd` with the error message "Run-time error 2147467259 (80004005)". Method 'Position' of object 'DataLabel' failed".

Looking at the chart, the label has been added, but it is still positioned inside the chart.

[image]

As you can see I've already positioned a label outside the chart for a different series, which is represented as a pie chart. While the series I am trying to add the label to is represented as a donut-chart.

Can't I have both the labels for the donut- and pie-chart on the outside? Isn't `xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd` a valid position for labels of a donut-chart? Or is the problem something else which eludes me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly you want to do the way you want to do it! The option to place the labels outside the chart is not available on the doughnut chart options:

[image: Missing options on doughnut chart]

like they do on a pie chart:

[image: Label position options on a pie chart]

However, you could perform a trick using a pie chart and a white circle to make it look like a doughnut by doing the following:

```
Sub AddCircle()
    'Get chart size and position:
        Dim CH01 As Chart: Set CH01 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart
        Dim OB01 As ChartObject: Set OB01 = CH01.Parent
        Dim x As Double: x = 0 'horizontal coordinate
        Dim y As Double: y = 0 'vertical coordinate
        Dim w As Double: w = 0 'width
        Dim h As Double: h = 0 'height
        x = OB01.Left
        y = OB01.Top
        w = OB01.Width
        h = OB01.Height
    'Adding the circle:
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, x + w / 2 - 20, y + h / 2 - 20, 40, 40).Name = "Circle01"
    'Formatting the circle:
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Circle01")
            .LINE.Visible = msoFalse
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
End Sub
```

And it works very nicely:

[image: Pie chart with a hole]

Had some fun "solving" this one...

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for that submenu of the formatting menu, to see what my options were - apparently the reason I couldn't find it is because it wasn't there! Anyway, I don't think your proposed solution will work for me, but thanks a ton for the effort :-)

Comment: I know. Since you're dealing with a combo chart, the trick may not be the right one. I posted it just because it was funny to do it (I'm such a nerd...!).

Answer (score 0):

Working with sinus and cosinus we can also calculate the outside position of the label. Following a VB snippet, how this can be done:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim cx
    Dim cy
    Dim x
    Dim y
    Dim radius
    Dim angle
    Dim new_radius
    Dim new_x
    Dim new_y

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Select
    cx = Selection.width / 2
    cy = Selection.height / 2

    For i = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count Step 1
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Select
        x = Selection.left + (Selection.width / 2)
        y = Selection.top + (Selection.height / 2)
        radius = Sqr(((x - cx) ^ 2) + ((y - cy) ^ 2))
        angle = WorksheetFunction.Atan2(y - cy, x - cx)
        new_radius = radius + 40
        new_x = cx + (Sin(angle) * new_radius)
        new_y = cy + (Cos(angle) * new_radius)
        Selection.left = new_x - (Selection.width / 2)
        Selection.top = new_y - (Selection.height / 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```